# GTK+ RadioButton Defaults - How to Work Around Ugly Hack?

Tags: python, gtk

I have a group of GTK+(3) RadioButtons. I don't think the version of GTK matters here, though.

When a RadioButton is toggled in my app, an action is taken and the GUI is updated with relevant information. This is all handled in a connected callback for the "toggled" signal. No problems.

Only non-toggled RadioButtons will trigger a "toggled" event. Makes sense.

Hence the problem arises - On app startup, the default RadioButton in the group will not trigger a "toggled" event because it is already toggled.

**How can I trigger this initial action on the default RadioButton?**

I am currently using an *ugly hack* - That is to add an invisible RadioButton, make this active  and then any of my actual RadioButtons can be valid defaults that trigger the "toggled" signal.

Answer (score 2):

The following will force the button to emit a `toggled` signal:

```
button.toggled()
```

This works because `toggled` method is already defined. However, if it wasn't you could still use the `emit` method to force any widget to emit any of their signals:

```
button.emit('toggled')
```

Comment: Perfect! I replaced set_active (for setting default) with toggled and that works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that fits your need, but you could also use `button.get_group()` and `button.get_active()` instead of watching the `toggled` event.

```
# python shell
button1 = gtk.RadioButton(None, "radio button1")
button2 = gtk.RadioButton(button1, "radio button2")
button3 = gtk.RadioButton(button1, "radio button3")

for b in button3.get_group():
    print b.is_active()
```

This should work for initial condition checking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know about this but it's sort of a workaround hack - or at the very least makes my code more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @Peter not sure if this is really a workaround. Depending on how you organized your code, it may be that GUI elements are not Python-coded. If so, the for loop I suggested is more like a general approach for the startup.